# How to use the initial value passed in the parameters as opposed to the updated value for a following calculation?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++

I'm using 4 and 5 as my input. The arithmetic:

a' = 4+5
b'= |4-5|

This issue is, "a" is being read in as 9 instead of 4 when the subtraction statement is executed. I would like to use the original user input "a" (which is  4) passed in the parameters as opposed to the "new a" (which is 9).

```
void update(int *a, int *b) 
{
    // Function will add and subtract updating the integers
    *a = *a + *b; //4+5=9 is stored in *a
    *b = abs(*a - *b); //*a is still 9 but needs to be original value of 4 
     //This should be |4-5|=1
}


int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    //Implementation    
    update(pa, pb);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b); // this output should be 9 and 1

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use a temporary variable?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass stuff to functions using pointers and using C-style I/O? You should learn about C++ I/O and references.

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary variable to help with the calculations.

```
void update(int *a, int *b) 
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = temp + *b;
    *b = abs(temp - *b);
}
```

Since you are using C++, I would suggest using reference types as arguments though.

```
void update(int& a, int& b) 
{
    int temp = a;
    a = temp + b;
    b = abs(temp - b);
}
```

and use it as:

```
update(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

References are way cooler than pointers.  C++ is way cooler than C. So use `iostream` and all that. Try to use descriptive names. When posting questions, don't forget the header files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void update(int &a, int &b) 
{
    int sum = a+b; 
    b = abs(a - b); 
    a = sum;
}

int main()  {
    int a {4};
    int b {5};

    update(a, b);
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the guidance. New guy here. Hopefully it's not too obvious!

Comment: Oh, it's obvious. We were all beginners at one time. In may case, that time was 1971.  No StackOverflow then, only IBM FORTRAN manuals in binders.

Comment: P.s. Everyone reads names. No one reads comments, except for people who don't trust them.

Comment: I've been reprimanded for loose conversation in the past. Being cautious as I may be banned from posting.

Comment: I was referring to function- and variable-names, and comments in computer code. If the names are good enough, the comments are just distractions. Usually. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **temp** variable, and the code should be optimize you don't need to declare **int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;** these variable instead you use reference **&**. The following code is the best solution of your code.

```
void update(int& a, int& b) 
{
    int temp = a;
    // Function will add and subtract updating the integers
    a = a + b; //4+5=9 is stored in *a
    b = abs(temp - b); //*a is still 9 but needs to be original value of 4 
     //This should be |4-5|=1
}


int main() 
{
    int a, b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    //Implementation    
    update(a, b);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b); // this output should be 9 and 1

    return 0;
}
```